# Can't toggle between Content and Source view in Android Designer (Xamarin in Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, android-layout, xamarin-studio

When using Android Designer in Visual Studio I can't toggle between the source and content of my view. From some reason in the same solution in Xamarin Studio I can do that. I have looked all over the place but it is not there, also from memory I was able to do this in this solution a while back.

I had a similar problem to this before which was solved once I renamed all the folders under Resources to lower case letters.

Below is a picture of the window with a missing and another one with the toggle buttons there (in Xamarin Studio).
[image]
 [image]

Cheers,